# If $U=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}K_j$ then $U=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}\mathring{K}_j$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain (connected open set), such that $U=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}K_j$ where each $K_j$ is a compact set, and $K_j\subset K_{j+1}$ for all $j\ge 1$.

Is the following proposition true?

$U=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}\mathring{K}_j$

$\mathring{K}_j:$ interior of $K_j$

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, consider $n=1$ with $U=(-1,1)$ and $K_n= [-1+1/n,-1/n]|\cup \{0\} \cup [1/n,1-1/n].$

Comment: As an aside, notice that $U \setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty \mathring{K}_j \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty \partial K_j$. Hence by the Baire category theorem, the points which are "missing" always form a set with empty interior. In the example above this set is $\{ 0 \}$. So in a sense the equality is "morally" correct, in that the points which are missed can only form a "small" set.